# mongodb aggregation lookup pipeline regex match

Tags: regex, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to do a regex match inside an aggregation pipeline `$lookup`

So lets assume the following query:

```
$lookup: {
   from: 'some-collection',
   let: {
      someIds: '$someIds'
   },
   pipeline: [
      {
         $match: {
            $expr: {
               $and: [
                  {
                     $in: ['$someId', '$$someIds']
                  },
                  {
                     $not: {
                        $eq: ['$status', 'archived']
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

This all works great, i can match on multiple conditions, and it works.

However if i want to add another condition using an array of regex i can't get it to work

```
$lookup: {
   from: 'some-collection',
   let: {
      someIds: '$someIds'
   },
   pipeline: [
      {
         $match: {
            $expr: {
               $and: [
                  {
                     $in: ['$someId', '$$someIds']
                  },
                  {
                     $not: {
                        $eq: ['$status', 'archived']
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     $in: ['$some-type', [/type1/, /type2/]]
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Why does this not work? as i understand it from the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/index.html#in-expressions) i should be able to use regex this way inside an `$in` operator, and i can confirm that it works, since we use it elsewhere. However nested within a `$lookup`pipeline it does not.

Is this a bug or am i overlooking something? Is there another way i can do this kind of regex match?

Answer (score 1):

Evidently, the problem appears to be that i was attempting to regex match inside the `$expr` operator, im unsure as to why it does not work, and i can't find anything within the documentation.

But by moving it to a seperate match within the pipeline it worked.

```
$lookup: {
   from: 'some-collection',
   let: {
      someIds: '$someIds'
   },
   pipeline: [
      {
         $match: {
            $expr: {
               $and: [
                  {
                     $in: ['$someId', '$$someIds']
                  },
                  {
                     $not: {
                        $eq: ['$status', 'archived']
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      },
      {
         $match: {
            some-type: {
               $in: [/type1/, /type2/]
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

If anyone can elaborate on why this is the case feel free

Comment: Put it in the same match stage
`{
         $match: {
           "some-type": {
               $in: [/type1/, /type2/]
            },
            $expr: {
               $and: [
                  {
                     $in: ['$someId', '$$someIds']
                  },
                  {
                     $not: {
                        $eq: ['$status', 'archived']
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }`